# Magento 2.0: How to override the name.phtml

Tags: magento2, template

How Can I override below **name.phtml** file from customer module

```
vendor/magento/module-Customer/view/frontent/templates/Widget/name.phtml
```

Comment: This is explained on the official [dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-sample.html). I'd recommended giving them a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the **name.phtml** by below path in your theme

```
app/design/frontend/YourTheme/Vendor/Magento_Customer/templates/widget/name.phtml
```

Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Patel +1 for you

Comment: can i add only html file in my theme ?

Comment: i have override name.phtml file but not display on frontend..plz give me any soluction?

Comment: Flush Magento cache?